# SagePay 'Form' Integration; unable to get SecurityKey value

Tags: opayo

We have a SagePay 'Form' integration on a website and we attempt (fail) to get the 'SecurityKey' value using 'SharedAPI' command 'getTransactionDetail'.

In the SagePay docs for 'SharedAPI' it shows how to create a 'getTransactionDetail' request, and the expected response has many properties and values returned in xml format; including a value for 'securitykey'.

But in our response we just get 'version' and 'timestamp' and nothing else.

*[sad-developer-emoji]

Someone at SagePay spoke about the user profile needs access to 'reporting'; but I cannot see how to set that in SagePay account?
The profile has access to all the settable things it can (EG: terminal; transactions; etc).
Not sure what we are doing wrong.

EG:

*REQUEST

```
<vspaccess>
    <command>getTransactionDetail</command>
    <vendor>[VendorName]</vendor>
    <user>[UserName]</user>
    <vpstxid>[VPSTxID]</vpstxid>
    <signature>[MD5HashSignature]</signature>
</vspaccess>

[MD5HashSignature] = CalculateMd5Hash(
    <command>getTransactionDetail</command>
    <vendor>[VendorName]</vendor>
    <user>[UserName]</user>
    <vpstxid>[VPSTxID]</vpstxid>
    <password>[UserPassword]</password>)
```

*RESPONSE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<vspaccess>
    <version>1.02</version>
    <timestamp>18/11/2020 08:14:54</timestamp>
</vspaccess>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to ensure that XML is in capitals when doing the POST, else you get the generic response outlined in the above post.

Comment: thanks for that, good to know! in our case though, we are posting form data in a url rather than xml